# games for teaching html

Tags: exercises, html

I have had good results, and happy students, using [CSS diner](https://flukeout.github.io/) to teach CSS selectors (I will share more in another question).

And one of my students asked me if there is a similar game for html.

Is there any site for learning html, gamified and in small increments, similar to what CSS diner offers for selectors?

My students are around 19 years old, though resources for younger students might also be useful.

Comment: What is the age range of the students?

Comment: Not entirely related, but here's a really nice game for teaching flexbox that I used to teach myself: https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Answer (score 1):

W3Schools have exercises that go up in small steps that go along with their tutorials https://www.w3schools.com/html/exercise.asp

For some project based exercises Raspberry Pi is good and I've used these in the classroom [https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/?software[]=html-css-javascript](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/?software%5B%5D=html-css-javascript)